# How to add Google adsense Adlinks at the middle of the post

Tags: 7, advertising

Hello I need to put adsense adlinks at the middle of the content or between paragraphs but I am not getting any modules to do that.Currently i use [Content Injector](http://drupal.org/project/adsense_injector) to display image ads at top and bottom of the post.

Comment: Can you explain why doesn't Content Injector do the job? From the module page it seems to me you can set up input filters with the `[adsense]` tags... Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

2 Methods:

1. Create two body fields, display adsense between the output of the two.
2. Output the block for the adsense code (I assume it is in a block) via PHP in your body.

`<?php
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 26);
print render($block);
?>`